# Update Table from Query using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

VBA/Macro newbie needing help with the above mentioned.

```
Table: Inventory

   Product      Value a    Value b
1. Product 1    0          0
2. Product 2    0          0
3. Product 3    0          0

Query: Qry

   Product     Value    VAL
1. Product 1   100      a
2. Product 2   200      a
3. Product 3   300      b
```

Result of Marco

```
Table: Inventory

   Product      Value a    Value b
1. Product 1    100        0
2. Product 2    200        0
3. Product 3    0          300
```

Without changing the schema or thinking of alternative methods: I specifically need a macro (not an update query) to update corresponding products in table.field "Inventory.Value" with a value from query "qry" depending on whether it is in column a or column b as stated in the table.

I know that there will be an iif statement involved and a insert into but for the life of me I just cannot make it work.

EDIT: I am open to alternative ideas with the same result.

This is a watered down version of the database.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Are you using a Macro or Data Macro? Data Macros are new in Access 2010 and not created in the Macros section, but from the Table. 2) Can you use a Macro in conjunction with an update query or is there some reason you can't use update queries?

Comment: This is probably going to show my ignorance but I haven't heard of Data Macro's before so I will definitely look into that. Up to now I've only used classic vba macro's. I also don't have the knowledge to pull this update query off, assuming that there will be sql involved.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the skeleton guys, it helped tremendously

This is the Macro (the fields and table names are different to my original post)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub Opdateer()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb

sql = "SELECT Orders.Warehouse, OrderDetail.Product, OrderDetail.OrderDetailStatus, Sum(OrderDetail.Qty_mt) AS SumOfQty_mt FROM Orders INNER JOIN OrderDetail ON Orders.ID = OrderDetail.OrderNumber GROUP BY Orders.Warehouse, OrderDetail.Product, OrderDetail.OrderDetailStatus;"

Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)

With rst
    Do Until rst.EOF
        If !OrderDetailStatus = "Allokeer" Then
             sql = "UPDATE [InventoryCT] SET [StockAllocated] = " & !SumOfQty_mt & " WHERE [ProductCT] = " & !Product & " ;"
            dbs.Execute (sql)
            Else
             sql = "UPDATE [InventoryCT] SET [StockOpgelaai] = " & !SumOfQty_mt & " WHERE [ProductCT] = " & !Product & " ;"
            dbs.Execute (sql)
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
rst.Close
dbs.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this;

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim sql As String

sql = <The sql string for your query>

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)

With rst
    Do Until .EOF
        If !VAL = "b" Then
             sql = "UPDATE Inventory SET [Value b] = " & !Value & " WHERE Product = '" & !Product "' ;"
             CurrentDB.Exectute sql
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: I'm getting Syntax errors:

Is it okay if the sql string goes over 3 lines?

dis CurrentDb stay the same or do I have to put in the Name of my DB?

Comment: You can split the code over three lines providing the SQL statement stays the same. CurrentDB stays as is

Comment: It refuses to go beyond the "sql =" bit

Comment: Can you post the code that you're trying? Clearly there's a problem with your SQL string - you're not including the "<" characters are you?